# elasticsearch php multiple names

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have FNAME and LNAME and Address that I want to search on. I want to search

```
FName = jo
LName = ro
Address = 34
```

that should give me all the records that have FName and LName starting with jo and ro (LIKE)
so if it was mysql it would be `FNmae Like jp% And LName Like ro% AND Address Like 34%`

so I have so far this

```
 $params = [
            'index' => $this->arrayES['index'],
            'type' =>  $this->arrayES['type'],
            'body' => [
                'query' => [
                    'match' =>  ["FName"=>"Jo"]
                ]
            ]
        ];
```

Problem with that is that it gives me only JO

and when I try to add LName and Address

```
'match' =>  ["FName"=>"Jo", "LName"=>"ro", "Address"=>"34"]
```

that errors out.

Need some help

thanks

** Expected Results **

```
FName             LName             Address
Jo                  Ro               34 W Ave
John                Rosa             3456 Havana Ave
Johnny              Ronnatte         341 House Rd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a way which allows to specify a very similar query to your SQL query, using the [`query_string` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html):

```
 $params = [
        'index' => $this->arrayES['index'],
        'type' =>  $this->arrayES['type'],
        'body' => [
            'query' => [
                'query_string' =>  [
                    'query' => 'FName:Jo* AND LName:ro* AND Address:34*'
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ];
```

Comment: that gave me all the "ro" for lastname only and firstname were all different. I need more kinda LIKE behavior. so Jo will match john etc

Comment: sorry that did not find any records :(

Comment: Even with the wildcard at the end of each value? Are you sure?

Comment: oh sorry I did not see the wild card